# Selenium WebDriverManager - Exception when running on Linux Server

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

I am new to Selenium and having some issues.

I am using the WebDriverManager in connection with Selenium. This is my code:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

When I run the code on my local system (Windows 10 OS), everything runs perfectly fine. When I run my code as a web application on our Linux Server (Ubuntu 18.04, Tomcat 9), I get the following exception:

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Exception reading resolution cache as a properties file
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.cache.ResolutionCache.<init>(ResolutionCache.java:86)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.getResolutionCache(WebDriverManager.java:1490)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.clearResolutionCache(WebDriverManager.java:780)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:1263)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:1060)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:393)
....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1035)
        at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.cache.ResolutionCache.<init>(ResolutionCache.java:75)
```

I am using Selenium 4.2.1 and Webdriver 5.1.0. 
On our Linux server, I have installed Google Chrome as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760085/how-do-you-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-16-04). When running

```
google-chrome --version
-> Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115
```

I get the shown result, so I think Chrome should be installed correctly.
Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is failing to create the resolution cache, which is a properties files created by default in the following path: `~/.cache/selenium`. You can try to create manually that path (although WebDriverManager should have been able to create when it does not exist).

In any case, to debug it properly, you need to check the WebDriverManager traces. For that, you need need to include a Logback configuration file (for example, like [this](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml)) in your project classpath. The name of this file should be `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` (if you want logs only for your tests) or `src/test/resources/logback.xml` (if you want logs for both tests and application code). Then, you can to use the following line to set the level to `TRACE`:

```
<logger name="io.github.bonigarcia" level="TRACE" />
```

For further info about logging with with SLF4J and Logback you can see the following [tutorial](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/logging-in-java-with-slf4j-and-logback).

Comment: Thank you for the input. Unfortunately, I did not manage to integrate logback with our platform, so I could not get those trace logs.
In the end I scaled back and downloaded a driver for my chrome and deactivated the chrome update. This is sufficient for my purposes but of course not the optimal solution.
Anyways, Thank you for the support.